# Angular js ng-bind-html not giving any output on input `{_}`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input data such like that:

```
<p>His dream is to study medicine, &nbsp;{_}?</p>
```

The character `{_}` make the output for `ng-bind-html` not give any output at all.

How to solve this problem?

You may refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imranhamzah/Lvc0u55v/12845/) for your extra information.

Answer (score 1):

If you include the **[`angular-sanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize)** script, inputs are sanitized by parsing the HTML into tokens

```js
var miAp = angular.module('miAp', ['ngSanitize']);

miAp.controller('demoController', function($scope) {
     $scope.bar = "<p>His dream is to study medicine, &nbsp;{_}?</p>";
  });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ngBind</title>
  
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  
  <script src="cookies.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="miAp" ng-controller="demoController">
   <div ng-bind-html="bar"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I want to try first.

Comment: Take sometimes to run ionic android..wait yea

Comment: I think is all ok, ngBindHtml requires the ngSanitize module. Simply that.

Comment: How to appy in ionic? I paste it as you do..but It does not work to me.

Comment: @Sajeetharan how to set in directive? It is working only on the controller ..right?
I will do like this in my code: `<div ng-html-bind="data.qst_cnt_text"></div>`. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign raw text as HTML. you need a conversion. $sce.trustAsHtml used to convert the raw text to HTMl. [Here is the link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce).